# Dashed border of a button changes to two solid borders when losing focus in HTA

Tags: css, vbscript, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, hta

In my HTA file I use a VBScript for changing the appearance of buttons when they are clicked. The clicked button gets a dashed border (as expected). But when the mouse leaves the button, the dashed border changes to a solid border plus a solid cyan inner border. How can I prevent this?

[image: left: after clicking the green button, right: after the mouse has left the green button]

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Dashed border test</title> 
    <HTA:APPLICATION 
        ID              = "test"
        APPLICATIONNAME = "test" >

    <script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
        Sub StopButton
            document.getElementsByTagName("button").item(0).style.border="dashed medium black"
            document.getElementsByTagName("button").item(1).style.border="none"
        End Sub
        Sub PlayButton
            document.getElementsByTagName("button").item(1).style.border="dashed medium black"
            document.getElementsByTagName("button").item(0).style.border="none"
        End Sub
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        button {width:100;height:80;font-size:24;}
    </style>
</head> 

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="vbscript:StopButton" style="background:blue; color:white;" value="Stop">Stop</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="vbscript:PlayButton" style="background:#0f0;" value="Play">Play</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

I use IE11. navigator.userAgent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"

EDIT

Additional information: when I click the background (white area), the button border changes back to dashed style (as in the left image).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code sample you posted. Do you have other styles in your actual code?

Comment: What I have posted is the complete file content. Have you saved the file as a .hta file? When I remove the HTA part and save it as .htm file (and add `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" />` for VBScript to work), the button border doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, I saved the file as .hta, and like I said, I cannot reproduce the issue. Clicking on either button puts the dashed line around the clicked button and removes it from the other button (without leaving any other border).

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer do you have? I had the same problem on three laptops all running IE11.

Comment: I tested with IE11 on Windows 8 and Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Thanks for testing! I use Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit with Service Pack 1. So I hope someone else can reproduce this bug.

Comment: The cyan "border" appears on a focused button. Usually you can get rid of it by setting `outline: none`. However, it seems, that IE11 somehow shows the cyan border inside the button, and styling the outline won't remove the border.

Comment: Since only HTA/IE 11 on Windows 7 seems to expose this behavior (I was able to reproduce it on my 32-bit Windows 7 test VM) I would consider it a bug.

Comment: We had this problem in every button. In our case we were using borders to control button border width and color. In our solution we simply remove the border and that fixed the cyan. In you case I don't see any border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I resolved.

First you open a global variable that's kept in memory. So when a user clicks either option. Once you've clicked it, these options help it to prevent default colors for highlighted html elements.

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Dashed border test</title> 
    <HTA:APPLICATION 
        id              = "test"
        applicationname = "test" 
        singleinstance="yes"
        contextmenu="yes"
        navigable="yes"
    />

    <script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
        stopclicked=false
        playclicked=false
        sub stopbutton(click)
            if ((click = true) OR (stopclicked = true)) then
                btnplay.classname="none"
                btnstop.classname="dashed"
                stopclicked=true
                playclicked=false
            else
                window.focus
            end if
        end sub
        sub playbutton(click)
            if ((click = true) OR (playclicked = true)) then
                btnplay.classname="dashed"
                btnstop.classname="none"
                stopclicked=false
                playclicked=true
            else
                window.focus
            end if
        end sub
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        button {width:100; height:80; font-size:24;}
        .dashed {border-style: dashed; border-style: black; border-style:medium;}
        #btnstop {background:blue; color:white;}
        #btnplay {background:#0f0;}
        .dashed:
    </style>
</head> 

<body link="" vlink="" alink=""> 
    <button id="btnstop" onclick="stopbutton(true)" onfocus="stopbutton(false)" value="Stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="btnplay" onclick="playbutton(true)" onfocus="playbutton(false)" value="Play">Play</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It works fine. It inspired me to an easier way: I just added `onmouseout="window.focus();"` to my buttons.